# Premature EOF error on parsing web page with JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, ioexception

I'm parsing hundreds of web pages using JSoup. Unfortunately, the whole process periodically fails due to a Premature EOF error.

Zeh kawd:

```
Document dom = Jsoup.parse(new URL("page").openStream(), "UTF-8", "page");
```

Zeh erraw:

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
```

Any idea on where it could come from? And how I could solve it...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The official cookbook (https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) suggests parsing a document from an url should be done like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
```

Maybe this'll help, good luck

Comment: Alrighty, I try this and I tell you. I was using another method because in another project I had troubles with the vanilla one. It may work now..........